# I don't know what is causing the segmentation fault in my code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm at my wit's end with this code and I am new to c++ so I don't even know where to begin to check for this error. What is causing the segmentation fault in my code and how do I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
  private:
    string name;
    int numClasses;
    vector<string> classList;

  public:
    Student (string nameVal, int numClassesVal, string classListArr[]);
    Student (string nameVal, int numClassesVal);
    Student (string nameVal);
    Student ();
    void setName(string nameVal);
    void setNumClasses(int numClassesVal);
    void setClassList(string classListArr[]);
    string getName();
    int getNumClasses();
    vector<string> getClassList();
    void input();
    void output();
    void reset();
};



int main ()
{
  Student user;
  string answer;
  int flag = 1;

  while (flag == 1)
  {
    user.input();
    user.output();

    cout << "Do you want to enter the new data? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    cin.ignore();

    if (answer == "n")
    {
      flag == 0;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

Student::Student (string nameVal, int numClassesVal, string classListArr[])
  : name(nameVal), numClasses(numClassesVal)
{
  string test = classListArr[0];
  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    if ( (x > 0) && (classListArr[x] == test))
      break;
    classListArr[x] = classList[x];
  }
}

Student::Student (string nameVal, int numClassesVal)
{
  name = nameVal;
  numClasses = numClassesVal;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    classList[x] = "";
  }
}

Student::Student (string nameVal)
{
  name = nameVal;
  numClasses = 0;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    classList[x] = "";
  }
}

Student::Student ()
{
  name = "";
  numClasses = 0;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    classList[x] = "";
  }
}


void Student::setName(string nameVal) {name = nameVal;}

void Student::setNumClasses(int numClassesVal) {numClasses = numClassesVal;}

void Student::setClassList(string classListArr[]) 
{
  string test = classListArr[0];
  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    if ( (x > 0) && (classListArr[x] == test))
      break;
    classListArr[x] = classList[x];
  }
}

string Student::getName() {return name;}

int Student::getNumClasses() {return numClasses;}

vector<string> Student::getClassList() {return classList;}

void Student::input()
{
  string temp;
  int classes;
  cout << "Input Student's Name:" << endl;
  getline(cin, temp);
  name = temp;
  cout << "Input Number of Classes:" << endl;
  cin >> classes;
  cin.ignore();
  numClasses = classes;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    if ( x == 9)
    {
      cout << "Input Last Class Name (Maximum of 10):";
      getline(cin, temp);
      classList[9] = temp;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Input Class Name:";
      getline(cin, temp);
      classList[x] = temp;
      cout << "Do you have any more classes? (y/n):";
      getline(cin, temp);

      if ( temp == "n")
        break;
    }
  }

}

void Student::output()
{
  cout << "Student Name: " << name << "\nNumber of Classes: " << numClasses << endl;


 cout << "Names of Classes: " << endl;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    if ( numClasses == 0 )
      break;
    if ( x == 0 )
      cout << "Names of Classes: \n";
    if ( classList[x] == "" )
      break;

    cout << "(" << x << ") " << classList[x] << "\n";
  }
}

void Student::reset()
{
  numClasses = 0;
  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    classList[x] = "";
  }
}
```

I tried changing the main function from before where I had a goto statement instead of a flag, and that didn't fix it. I think it's the cin.getline() but I am not sure.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `flag == 0;` -> `flag = 0;`,

Comment: The `Student` constructor assigns to `classList[x]` without ever creating that element.

Comment: A suggestion: don't write much code without compiling and testing. Write a function. Compile and test it so you know it works. Write another function. Compile and test  Don't write an entire program and THEN try to compile test the entire program because you wind up having to sift through tonnes of errors all at the same time. Who knows what interacts with what making one bug worse, hiding other bugs and generally turning one problem at a time in a relatively small space into N-squared problems scattered over hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior in this code (and the other constructors):

```
Student::Student ()
{
  name = "";
  numClasses = 0;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    classList[x] = "";
  }
}
```

You never allocated any elements in the `classList` vector, so the reference to `classList[x]` is out of bounds. You should use `.push_back()` to add new elements to the vector:

```
Student::Student ()
{
  name = "";
  numClasses = 0;

  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    classList.push_back("");
  }
}
```

Or before the loop you could do `classList.reserve(10);` to make room for 10 elements.

See [C++ Tutorial: A Beginner's Guide to std::vector](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm)